# Cant read console logs in a headless browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Im running puppeteer in a node js project to try and get the console logs of a URL. It only seems to work with the initial console logs at startup that arn't warnings or errors.

What I would like is to view all of the logs just like you would in a normal browser for the first x amount of seconds. Here is my code:

```
const puppeteerOptions =
{
    headless: true,
    args: ['--disable-gpu', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-first-run', '--no-sandbox', '--no-zygote', '--single-process'],
};

(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            const browser = await HeadlessBrowser.launch(puppeteerOptions);
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            page.on('console', msg =>
            {
                console.log(msg.text());
            });

            await page.goto('https://uk.yahoo.com/');
            await browser.close();
        }
        catch(e) {return reject(e);}
    })();
```

In this case im going to the yahoo site which contains lots of console logs but doesnt display any here. I think its because they are logging after the site has loaded.

As for reading the logs in the first x amount of seconds, I have tried adding this before closing the browser but all that did was stall the closing and no console logs came through.

await page.waitFor(10000);

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1512

Comment: Thanks its displaying all of the ones loaded before the dom has loaded which is great but do you know how I would log the ones that appear for the next 10 seconds or so. @George

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this and here is the correct way.

```
const delay = 5000; //Milliseconds, 5 seconds

(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            const browser = await HeadlessBrowser.launch(puppeteerOptions);
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            page.on('console', msg =>
            {
                //do whatever
            });

            page.on('pageerror', error =>
            {
                // do whatever
            });

            /*
            page.on('requestfailed', request => {
                //Didn't need
            });
            */

            await page.goto(data.url);
            await page.waitFor(delay);
            await browser.close();

            Utils.logger('Finished reading console logs.');
            return resolve();
        }
        catch(e) {return reject(e);}
    })();
```